# 120 V motor with only T1, T4 2 and 8 reversible

Tags: motor

This is on an an antique lathe.  Someone tried to replace the rotten wire and never got it right. There are 4 terminals on the motor
T1, T4, 2 and 8.
I expect T1 and T4 will go to line but how to wire drum switch with 2 and 8?  It seems all new diagrams list all as T1 to T8.  Perhaps 8 is T8?

Comment: if there is a label on the motor, then please add a picturevto your post

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the motor and the diagrams you refer to in your question

Comment: No label, old or removed in the past 75 years.

Comment: I can't figure out how to upload photo here.